# Custom hook and dynamic useEffect dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm using this `useFetch` custom hook in multiple components.

```js
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import {getToken} from './../services/token'

const useFetch = (url) => {

    const [data,setData]       = useState(null);
    const [error,setError]     = useState(null);
    const [loading,setPending] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {

        (async()=>{

          const abortCont = new AbortController();
          const token     = await getToken();

          try {

            setPending(true);

            const response = await fetch(url,{
              signal  : abortCont.signal,

              headers : {
                "Content-Type"  : "application/json",
                "Authorization" : "Bearer "+token
              }

            });

            const result    = await response.json();

            setData(result);
            setPending(false);

          } catch (err) {

            if(err.name === 'AbortError'){
                abortCont.abort();
                return;
            }

            setError(String(err));
            setPending(false);

          }

        })()

      }, [])

    return {data,error,loading}
}

export default useFetch;
```

And I import it in a users components as below.

```js
const {data,error,loading} = useFetch('http://localhost:4040/users');
```

Normally I pass the second parameter of `UseEffect` like `[users.length]` to make the users data reactive but as this is a custom hook and being used in many components,
How can I make the users data to be reactive when users data was changed or updated?

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-wood-3lxrv?file=/src/user-list.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the dependency array as the optional parameter to your custom hook.

```
const useFetch = async (url, deps) => {

const [data,setData]       = useState(null);
const [error,setError]     = useState(null);
const [loading,setPending] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {

    (async()=>{

      const abortCont = new AbortController();
      const token     = await getToken();

      try {

        setPending(true);

        const response = await fetch(url,{
          signal  : abortCont.signal,

          headers : {
            "Content-Type"  : "application/json",
            "Authorization" : "Bearer "+token
          }

        });

        const result    = await response.json();

        setData(result);
        setPending(false);

      } catch (err) {

        if(err.name === 'AbortError'){
            abortCont.abort();
            return;
        }

        setError(String(err));
        setPending(false);

      }

    })()

  }, deps || [])

    return {data,error,loading}
}

export default useFetch;
```

Then call it like

```
const {data,error,loading} = useFetch('http://localhost:4040/users', [users.length]);
```

**EDIT**

In your case you want to have some more control over the rendering. So i'll say you have to modify your hook to support setting data for your mounted component.

```
const useFetch = async (url, holded, setHolded) => {

const [data,setData]       = useState(null);
const [error,setError]     = useState(null);
const [loading,setPending] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {

    (async()=>{

      const abortCont = new AbortController();
      const token     = await getToken();

      try {

        setPending(true);

        const response = await fetch(url,{
          signal  : abortCont.signal,

          headers : {
            "Content-Type"  : "application/json",
            "Authorization" : "Bearer "+token
          }

        });

        const result    = await response.json();

        setData(result);
        if(setHolded) {
            setHolded(result);
        }
        setPending(false);

      } catch (err) {

        if(err.name === 'AbortError'){
            abortCont.abort();
            return;
        }

        setError(String(err));
        setPending(false);

      }

    })()

  }, (holded && setHolded && [holded,setHolded,url]) || [url])

    return {data,error,loading}
}

export default useFetch;
```

Then call it like

```
const {data,error,loading} = useFetch('http://localhost:4040/users', users, setUsers);
```

Comment: Thanks, btw how do you obtain the users array in the component you called it? I mean `[users.length]`.

Comment: @PoeEain Thats upto the implementation, would be somewhere you call `setUsers`

Comment: I tried adding this `setUsers(data.users)` after the fetch call, It shows `Too many re-render` error. I even try to wrap in if statement like `if(data){ setUsers(data.users) } `, it outputs the same error.

Comment: Can you add some more of the code so that i could see the problem?

Comment: Could you please check on [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-wood-3lxrv?file=/src/user-list.js) ? Thanks

Comment: You’re setting the state inside a render cycle. The state must only be set via some hook or callback. I’m editing my answer. hopefully now it will get your problem solved.